# improving the sql query for a dbms problem

Tags: sql

I want to write a SQL query for the problem as defined below, my answer for the first part is as below, but I am not sure about the answer, can anyone help me? Is the answer correct, or if not, how can I improve it?
For the second part can anyone help me?

Let us consider the following relational schema about physicians and departments:

- `PHYSICIAN` (PhysicianId, Name, Surname, Specialization, Gender, BirthDate, Department);

  Let every physician be univocally identified by a code and characterized by a name, a surname, a specialization (we assume to record exactly one specializa- tion for each physician), a gender, a birth date, a department (each physician is assigned to one and only one department), and a home city.
  Let every city be univocally identified by its name and characterized by the region it belongs to.
- `DEPARTMENT` (Name, Building, Floor, Chief)

Let every department be univocally identified by a name and characterized by its location (building and floor) and chief. Let us assume that a physician can be the chief of at most one department (the department he/she belongs to). We do not exclude the possibility for two distinct departments to be located at the same floor of the same building.

- `BELONGS`  TO(City,Region)

Let us assume that a physician can be the chief of at most one department (the department he/she belongs to). We do not exclude the possibility for two distinct departments to be located at the same floor of the same building.

I want to formulate an SQL query to compute the following data (exploiting aggregate functions only if they are strictly necessary):
• the departments such that (i) all their physicians reside in the region Piemonte and (ii) at least one of them resides in the city Torino.

My answer for the fist part is as below:
for the second part, I don't know how to solve it .

```sql
create view X{
select b.city, b.region, b.department
from physician p inner join belong-to b on b.city= p.homecity 
where b.region="Piemonte"


select name
from department d
where exists( select*
from X
where p.department =d.name )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Select Distinct b.department
From physician p 
Join belong-to b on b.city = p.homecity 
Where Exists (Select 1 From belong-to b2 Where b2.city = p.homecity AND b2.region = "Piemonte")
      Exists (Select 1 From belong-to b2 Where b2.city = p.homecity AND b2.city = "Torino") AND
      NOT Exists (Select 1 From belong-to b2 Where b2.city = p.homecity AND b2.region <> "Piemonte") AND
```

Comment: thank you . the problem is two part, this answer is the second part , right?

Comment: also also what does Select 1 means?  and why you use d.id? because department does not have id

Comment: It is espected to solve parts both 1 and 2. Select 1 is because Select needs to return "something" but at this point (inside an Exists) we dont care "what" it does return.'

Comment: "d.id" it think I copied it from you original post.

Comment: yes it was wrong that's why I edited very soon, so can you help me with the edited post?

Comment: thanks a lot, I would be grateful if you tell me the last line of code, what is doing?

Comment: You need that ALL the physicians reside in the region Piemonte, the last line ensures than NO ONE resides in another region.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I think the part 2 should be done in a different way because it is it wants  at least one of them resides in the city Torino., it say at least one of them

Comment: I changed (again) my answer to fix a syntax error. There are 3 Exists in the Where. The first is to ensure that at least one physician resides in Piemonte, the second is to ensure that at least one is from Torino and the third is to ensure that no one is from another region but Piemonte

Answer (score 0):

I would use aggregation:

```
select p.department
from physician p join
     belongsto b
     on p.homecity = b.city
group by p.department
having sum(case when b.region <> 'Piemonte' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and  -- no Piemonte
       sum(case when p.homecity = 'Torino' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1       -- at least one Torino
```